# quantmod, not able to loop through chartSeries

Tags: dynamic-chart-series

```
install.packages("quantmod")
library(quantmod)

company_list <- c("AMD","AMZN","JPM","GOOG","COST")
for (i in 1:length(company_list)){
  symbol <- company_list[i]
  data_in <- as.name(symbol)
  getSymbols(symbol)
  chartSeries(data_in,subset="last 9 months")
  addSMA(10,col="blue")
  addSMA(20,col="red")
}
```

Error in try.xts(x, error = "chartSeries requires an xtsible object") : 
  chartSeries requires an xtsible object

somehow this code stuck at chartSeries(data_in,subset="last 9 months")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to give the xts object to `chartSeries`, with `get(symbol)`:

```
company_list <- c("AMD","AMZN")
for (i in 1:length(company_list)){
  symbol <- company_list[i]
  getSymbols(symbol)
  chartSeries(get(symbol),subset="last 9 months")
  addSMA(10,col="blue")
  addSMA(20,col="red")
}
```

Comment: get(symbol) is the key